# permission denied while using fb_graph rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

SA
I have a application written in RubyonRails and I want to make him post periodically on facebook fan page.
I used [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem to do that.
I created my facebook app and I get my Access Token to use it but when I use this peace of code

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
me.feed!(
:message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
:picture => 'https://graph.facebook.com/matake/picture',
:link => 'http://github.com/nov/fb_graph',
:name => 'FbGraph',
:description => 'A Ruby wrapper for Facebook Graph API'
)
```

I get permission denied error message.

How can I get the permission to post on my fan page wall?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you requested the token, did you specify "manage_pages" as part of your scope?

Comment: here's a link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: essentially: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages`  That link will redirect to the given URL with a code, which you then use to get your access token.  I use the OAuth2 ruby gem for this purpose.

Comment: ok, what should i replace YOUR_URL with?

Comment: you need an endpoint on your server which expects the redirect, with the param `code`.  You then turn around and resend that `code` to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URLclient_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=CODE`.  This will return your access token, if successful, or some error JSON otherwise.  It is that access token that you provide to fb_graph.

Comment: thank you I will do this solution. you can write this as an answer to vote up it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to the docs:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

There are several flows, but essentially, you provide a link for the client to authenticate at facebook:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_U‌​RL&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages`

After authing this redirects to a URL on your site prepared to handle the param `code`, which you then turn around and send back to facebook for your access_token, which you provide to fb_graph.

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_ur‌​i=YOUR_URLclient_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=CODE`

There are other permissions as well, so you might want to check the facebook docs to see if there are more you need.

Facebook uses OAuth 2 for auth, and there are several ruby gems you can use to facilitate this process slightly, including the [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem.

Answer (score 0):

The app ID you specified must be wrong. please cross check that. A sample appID looks like this

```
  APP_ID="162221007183726"
```

Also check whether you have used any call back url. The url should point to a server. Your cannot use your localhost/ local IP  there.

A similar nice rails plugin for Facebook app using Rails3 is Koala gem

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails

http://blog.twoalex.com/2010/05/03/introducing-koala-a-new-gem-for-facebooks-new-graph-api/